# Does anyone know what is it I have to do exactly to resolve this fly deployment issue?

Tags: deployment, ghost-blog, http-status-code-502, fly

When trying to visit the newly deployed app, I'm getting the error:"This page isn't working HTTP ERROR 502"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNH2A.png)

I'm really not sure what to do, if someone has any idea, your help is more than welcome.